# Google colaboratory run code locally

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, collaboration, gurobi, google-colaboratory

Is it possible to run Google Colaboratory scripts in my computer locally?
If not, why it has been designed in that way?

I would like to work collaboratively in short code scripts without having to use version control systems such as Github and being able to do so using Windows OS, in a simple way like sending a link for the code in some platform like Google Drive.

For the moment I have not been able to do this using Jupyter Notebook, because it seems that, at least for now, it would be necesary to work in a Unix-like Operative System. Another possiblity I have found (but not been able to perform) is using the nbviewer webservice. The instructions to set it up are a bit complicated or need special requirements such as having Windows Pro or Enterprise editions.

I found the Google Colaboratory tool that allows me to do this but there are some libraries that I am not able to import/use on it (gurobipy). Also there is the issue that some of these libraries connect to software that need some licenses in order to be used (I use them with the license of my university).

I would like to know if there is a way to run the code locally (without having to download the script each time) or another tool to achieve this.

Here are some related questions:

https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/29

[How to directly upload a Jupyter notebook from Local Machine onto Google Collab? Is there a way to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849938/how-to-directly-upload-a-jupyter-notebook-from-local-machine-onto-google-collab?rq=1)

[Google Colab is very slow compared to my PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360888/google-colab-is-very-slow-compared-to-my-pc)

[wish to use colaboratory. What is simplest way to do a get drive file to python (encapsulated)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949235/wish-to-use-colaboratory-what-is-simplest-way-to-do-a-get-drive-file-to-python/47962294#47962294)

Please let me know if I have misunderstood something in my research or have missed some option to do this things.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don’t need nbviewer webservice. Colab can display the notebook already. Please try to learn what it can do. Also specify clearly what you want to do but cannot.

Comment: I am not able to work with the gurobipy library on it. I have used it for other things without any problem. That is the reason why I would like to know if it is possible to run it locally or if there is another option or tool to do this.

Answer (score 11):

You can use Colab with a local Jupyter backend, thereby providing easy access to local files and a persistent environment, but still being able to share notebooks using Drive.

Instructions for using local Jupyter with Colab are here:
https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

Comment: is it possible to _sync_ a local Jupyter notebook with Google colaboratory? For now, once I upload a local notebook, to keep things in sync, I can at best use the Jupyter backend through the Colaboratory interface.

Comment: My local Jupyter notebooks are not synced to Google Drive as they are part of a git-repo. I personally avoid mixing git-repos with other file-hosting services (Dropbox/Google Drive ...).